# i am getting issue for screen sizes 5.5 or above

Tags: android, layout

my xml layout is working fine, everything coming in single screen no need to scroll in below 5.5 screens 
but in 5.5  not able to see all thing in single screen i have to scroll to see remaining content that is two buttons showing bottom `

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-A7dHsM4QkmZVNjb2Z5RXJyZjg/view?usp=sharing) is the screenshot.

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_container"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/left_p"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/left_arrow" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_p"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="60dp"
            android:paddingRight="60dp"
            android:text="Monday, 24 August, 2015"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/right_p"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/right_arrow" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/morning_layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/inactive_box"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/morning_icon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/morning_icon" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/morning"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Morning"
                            android:textColor="@color/SlateGray" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab_list1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/noon_layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/inactive_box"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/noon_icon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/noon_icon" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/noon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Noon"
                            android:textColor="@color/SlateGray" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab_list2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/evening_layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/inactive_box"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/evening_icon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/evening_icon" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/evening"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Evening"
                            android:textColor="@color/SlateGray" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab_list3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/night_layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/inactive_box"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/night_icon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/night_icon" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/night"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Night"
                            android:textColor="@color/SlateGray" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab_list4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/pillbox"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/pill_box_icon" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pill_box"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Pill Box"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/plus_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/plus_icon" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Now tell me: why did you nest all those LinearLayouts? **Nested layouts are evill**, because they **badly affect the performances** and overcomplicate your structure without any reason.

Comment: if i did without nest problem will solve??

Comment: Not necessarily. But at least it will be simpler to dig into what's happening, since you'll have less layouts to control and manage. And possibly less inherited margins and paddings. There's a difference in the behavior of phones and tablets. While the formers follow the `density` rules (...), the latter follow the `sw*dp | sh*dp` rules (...)

Comment: can i know how to solve this...?

Comment: Yes you can. It's enough to google for `android support multiple screen` and read the official docs.